# C# SendGrid - SendAsync Method Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

I have followed a tutorial to setup SendGrid in my C# ASP.NET application.
I have the following code in my IdentityConfig.cs as suggested:

```
using SendGrid;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new EmailAddress(
                            "johnlowry484@gmail.com", "John Lowry");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
        myMessage.HtmlContent = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        **var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);**

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

The line `var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);` is causing the error:

> The type or namespace 'Web' could not be found

Everywhere I look online, `SendGrid.Web(credentials)` is valid, but it isn't for me.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
John

Comment: What is the version of .net and sendgrid that you are using? May be a mismatch of versions issue.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5.2 and SendGrid.9.5.0

Comment: What happens if you replace `new Web` with `new SendGrid.Web`?

Comment: I get the error message <The type or namespace 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'SendGrid'

Comment: Have you tried this sample code, which doesn't use `Web` https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html ?

Comment: Did that work for you @Johnathon ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SmtpClient` to create an instance for the credentials.

```
var Smtp = new SmtpClient()
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"])
};
...
await Smtp.SendAsync(myMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using V3 you need to refer to the documentation 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/csharp.html

```
// using SendGrid's C# Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Execute().Wait();
        }

        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

> Edited :  `You can downgrade to 6.0.1 and it will work fine`